# How can one check for a binary in the GAC in a WiX installer?

Tags: wix

I have an application which depends on the Team Foundation Server "Object Model", and looks for such binaries in the GAC. This means that clients of the app need to install Visual Studio, or the [standalone TFS object model](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75) in order to use the application.

I would like the installer to detect that the TFS bits aren't installed, and fail to install appropriately if they are not.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use registrySearch for this need.

```
<Property Id="TFS_OBJECT_MODEL_VERSION">
      <RegistrySearch Id="TFSSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\5CDE7BA1198D5C43F91FEBA658CA4CB4" Name="ProductName" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
</Property>
<Condition Message='TFS Object Model is required to install this product'>Installed OR TFS_OBJECT_MODEL_VERSION</Condition>
```

If you need to ge the location of the installation, you can use another registry path to get the location of the TFS component, but I suppose the code I provided is enough for you needs.

Comment: It is ProductID of the MSI which installed the TFS. At least on my machine, where it was installed with VS 2010. But I suppose this ID is the same for every installation of TFS object model 2010

Comment: ProductID usually changes for Major upgrades of product. Otherwise it is left the same. You can read more here http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization